# Oracle script to create dynamic query based on SQL held in a field

Tags: oracle, loops, dynamic, bulk-collect

Where a user gives a set of inputs from one table, e.g. "request_table" a:

| User Input | Value | Field Name in Database |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product | Deposit | product_type |
| Deposit Term (months) | 24 | term |
| Deposit Amount | 200,000 | amount |
| Customer Type | Charity | customer_type |
| Existing Customer | Y | existing_customer |

Would like to use the product selection to pick out SQL scripts embedded in a "pricing_table" b, where the price is made up of components, each of which are affected by one or more of the above inputs:

| Product | Grid | Measures | Value1 | Value1Min | Value1Max | Value2 | Value2Min | Value2Max | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 0 | 12 |  | 0 | 100000 | 1 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 12 | 36 |  | 0 | 100000 | 2 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 36 | 9999 |  | 0 | 100000 | 3 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 0 | 12 |  | 100000 | 500000 | 1.1 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 12 | 36 |  | 100000 | 500000 | 2.1 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 36 | 9999 |  | 100000 | 500000 | 3.1 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 0 | 12 |  | 500000 | 99999999 | 1.2 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 12 | 36 |  | 500000 | 99999999 | 2.2 |
| Deposit | Term_Amount | a.term>=b.value1min and a.term<b.value2 max and a.amount>=b.value2min and a.amount<b.value2max |  | 36 | 9999 |  | 500000 | 99999999 | 3.2 |
| Deposit | Customer_Type | a.customer_type=b.value1 | Personal |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |
| Deposit | Customer_Type | a.customer_type=b.value1 | Charity |  |  |  |  |  | 0.1 |
| Deposit | Customer_Type | a.customer_type=b.value1 | Business |  |  |  |  |  | -0.1 |
| Deposit | Existing_Customer | a.existing_customer=b.value1 | Y |  |  |  |  |  | 0.1 |
| Deposit | Existing_Customer | a.existing_customer=b.value1 | N |  |  |  |  |  | 0 |

Where the query is: select distinct measures from pricing_table where product=(select product_type from request_table). This gives multiple rows where SQL logic is held.
Would like to run this SQL logic in a LOOP, e.g.:
select b.* from pricing_table b where :measures
This would return all rows where the specific metrics are matched.
Doing it this way as the exact columns in the input can grow to hundreds, so don't want a really wide table.
Any help appreciated thanks.

I've creating tables but am unsure how to loop the measures, and apply the values from that field in a looped query thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a PL/SQL pipelined function, you can build the SQL query and open a cursor on it, loop on the results and PIPE the rows.

Comment: Great thanks I'll look into using that.